# Ubuntu 22.04 install dual boot with Windows 10 - running slowly and apps crashing randomly

Tags: dual-boot, crash, 22.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10 on my HP Pavilion laptop (model HP Pavilion 15 cs3099tx, 8GB Ram and two built in Hard drives, one SSD containing the Windows install and one standard HD that has been partitioned for the Ubuntu install). The install went smoothly and both OSes are functioning well.  However when running Ubuntu it does run very slowly at times. It can take 30 seconds plus from powering on to getting to the log in screen. Firefox and other apps can slow to a crawl and then crash at random times.

I installed Steam and was playing a game through Steam Play and Proton which crashes after about 5 mins of play time - that could just be a game issue, not related to the OS at all.

When I restart and boot into Windows, it works perfectly fine, no lag and no random crashes. So it appears only Ubuntu is affected.

I am not new to Ubuntu, I have dabbled in it at times in the past and also have a virtual box set up as well. But I'm not a programmer/developer so have limited confidence when it comes to tinkering with technical issues related to the set up without good step by step guides.

I am just looking for advice/tips from users of what I should be looking for with my set up that might improve the speed and reliability.

Comment: The perceived (and very real) slowness in boot and launch times as compared to Windows likely has to do with installing Ubuntu to a HDD.  Laptop HDDs are often 5400rpm which makes them even slower. As far as applications crashing, that may be a separate issue. However if all of the applications that are crashing are Windows software running on emulation or compatibility layers (incl Proton) that is unfortunately par for the course. Windows software isn't written to run on Ubuntu and you'll need to troubleshoot each application's specific quirks individually

Comment: It's all software that can crash randomly, the Firefox native ubuntu app does, and others. Take your point about HDD v SSD speeds and maybe I have just grown used to the speed of SSD. It just felt slower than I was expecting and had experienced in the past with Ubuntu.

Comment: You might want to keep a resource monitor open to see if you can detect if any resources are maxed out when the crash occurs.

Comment: @Nmath do you think the built in "System Monitor" is appropriate for monitoring like that, or is there a better one you would recommend?

Comment: Use whatever resource monitor is easier for you to use and read.